# how to make jquery animation fast?

Tags: jquery, performance, animation

jQuery animation is too slow on IE. 
Particularly background image animation.

Is there other animation library faster than jQuery animation?

Comment: What is exactly the animation that you use? Fade in, out, animate, some very complex algorithm? Perhaps you are just doing it wrong or using too much unneeded stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its a browser issue, so there is no "magic" to improve it, you can try to :

- make your animations more simple
- use a simpler dom structure in your animated objects
- decrease the FX Interval frame rate http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/
- think about a degraded / flash Solution for IE

Answer (score 1):

Flash outperforms javascript with large images